# MongoDB sharding of existing database

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have completed the process of mongoDB sharding and everything works fines. However new databases on **mongos** port 27017 are not showing me the existing database option for sharding which I used to connect on **mongod** port 27017.

How can I shard the existing database?

Do I have to change ports in these commands (they are for localhost setup only):

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath cfg0 --port 26050 --fork --logpath log.cfg0 --logappend
mongod --configsvr --dbpath cfg1 --port 26051 --fork --logpath log.cfg1 --logappend
mongod --configsvr --dbpath cfg2 --port 26052 --fork --logpath log.cfg2 --logappend
mongod --shardsvr --replSet a --dbpath a0 --port 27000 --logpath log.a0 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50
mongod --shardsvr --replSet a --dbpath a1 --port 27001 --logpath log.a1 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50
mongod --shardsvr --replSet a --dbpath a2 --port 27002 --logpath log.a2 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50
mongod --shardsvr --replSet b --dbpath b0 --port 27100 --logpath log.b0 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50
mongod --shardsvr --replSet b --dbpath b1 --port 27101 --logpath log.b1 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50
mongod --shardsvr --replSet b --dbpath b2 --port 27102 --logpath log.b2 --fork --logappend --smallfiles --oplogSize 50
mongos --configdb webdev.local:26050,webdev.local:26051,webdev.local:26052 --fork --logappend --logpath log.mongos0
```

Comment: The question was hard to read; reformatted it.